# Easiest way to detect/listen to MySQL database changes from Android application?

Tags: android, mysql

My question is stated in the title.

More specifically? In my MySQL database I have a table 'events' and each time an event is added/removed I would like to update the points on a Map on my android application.

If possible, a tutorial or code example would also be very much useful as I am still new to and exploring Android.

Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use C2DM to notify your Android application about database changes on your server:

https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/

**Update**

> Important: C2DM was officially deprecated on June 26, 2012, and has been shut down completely as of October 20, 2015. Existing C2DM developers are encouraged to migrate to Google Cloud Messaging (GCM). See the C2DM-to-GCM Migration document for more information. Developers must use GCM for new development.

Now a days C2DM is deprecated so you need to use Firebase or GCM(also deprecated)

[FCM link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)

> Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) is the new version of GCM. It inherits the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus new features! See the FAQ to learn more. If you are integrating messaging in a new app, start with FCM. GCM users are strongly recommended to upgrade to FCM, in order to benefit from new FCM features today and in the future.

[GCM link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)

Comment: First time I come across this C2DM but seems like a promising solution as far as I've quickly read.
Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: From developers.google.com: Deprecated. Important: C2DM was officially deprecated on June 26, 2012, and has been shut down completely as of October 20, 2015. Existing C2DM developers are encouraged to migrate to Google Cloud Messaging (GCM). See the C2DM-to-GCM Migration document for more information. Developers must use GCM for new development.

Answer (score 0):

So, First -> No MySQL in Android -> you will have to use SQLite .

You will be entering data in your database somewhere in your application code -> there you can call a function which will refresh your map-view with new data.

Other than that... if you can provide much details of your application then may be someone can help you.

Comment: I know that MySQL is not in Android. I simply connect to the external database through my Android (PHP in between obviously).

I am just asking if there's a way to "listen" to changes made in my MySQL database as it is configured now. I am not going to switch to SQLite.

Put simply:
Android connects to MySQL database through PHP.
I want to update a map in my Android application when an event in table 'events' of MySQL is deleted/added etc.

Comment: @bubbly PHP is not important here, PHP is a server-side script, what you get is a simple HTTP response.

Comment: @Mustafa I agree. I was just thinking maybe PHP will do the "listening" work and pass info to Android... Since Android cannot communicate directly with MySQL, that is what I am coming to understand.